# Pipline Mongodb Aggregation Order

Tags: mongodb

I accidentally tried to execute Two aggregation commands on publis collection:

```
db.publis.aggregate([  
    { $group : { _id : "$publisher" , count:{$sum:1} }  }   , 
    {$project: { _id:0 , count:1}  }  
])

db.publis.aggregate([ 
    {$project: { _id:0 , count:1}  }   , 
    { $group : { _id : "$publisher" , count:{$sum:1} }  }   ])
```

could you please,  tell me how this aggregate function works exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation will read documents from the input collection, and then pass the documents along the pipeline through each stage in turn.  The stages can remove documents from the stream, create new documents, or modify the existing ones.

**Project**
The [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#project-aggregation) stage selects fields to include in the document or exclude from the document, and can use operators to generate new values.

In your examples `_id:0` tells it to remove the `_id` field before passing the document along, and the `count:1` tells it to include the `count` field.

Because you have explicitly included a field, all fields not mentioned will be excluded.

**Group**
The [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-aggregation) stage will group the documents by the specified `_id` value, and apply any specified accumulator expressions.

In your example, this will group the documents by the value of the `publisher` field, and increment the `count` field by 1 for each document in the group.

-

Order does matter.

**Examples**

Consider a sample data set of 3 documents:

```
[
  {_id:1, publisher:"barnes"},
  {_id:2, publisher:"noble"},
  {_id:3, publisher:"barnes"}
]
```

Since the sample pipelines do not start with a match stage, all of the documents will be in the stream at the start.

**Group then Project**

In the first pipeline you provided, the first stage is:

```
{ $group : { _id : "$publisher" , count:{$sum:1} }  }
```

After this stage the documents in the pipeline stream will look like:

```
[
  { _id: "barnes", count: 2},
  { _id: "noble", count:1}
]
```

Then the second stage

```
{$project: { _id:0 , count:1}  }
```

eliminates all fields except `count`, leaving

[
 {count: 2},
 {count: 1}
]

**Project then Group**

In your second pipeline example, the stages are in the reverse order, so starting with the same set of input documents:

```
[
  {_id:1, publisher:"barnes"},
  {_id:2, publisher:"noble"},
  {_id:3, publisher:"barnes"}
]
```

The first stage

```
{$project: { _id:0 , count:1}  }
```

Eliminates all fields except the count, leaving:

```
[
 {},
 {},
 {}
]
```

The the second stage

```
{ $group : { _id : "$publisher" , count:{$sum:1} }  }
```

groups by `_id` which is missing in all of the documents at this point, so `$group` will use `null` as the value, and it will add the count and increment it for each document, leaving:

```
[
 { _id:null, count:3}
]
```

Comment: Thanks! that was enlighting!  interesting !